# GWT cell table, how to clear input of EditTextCell?

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I have column with EditTextCell. I some condition I would like to clear data from that cell.

In column `FieldUpdater` in method update I do some checks.

How I can clear this data in update method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `clearViewData` and `redrawRow`:

```
final CellTable<MyTableType> table = new CellTable<MyTableType>();

final MyEditTextCell cell = new MyEditTextCell();

Column<MyTableType, String> column = new Column<MyTableType, String>(cell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(MyTableType object) {
        if(object.getValue() == null)
            return "";
        else
            return object.getValue();
    }
};
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<MyTableType, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, MyTableType object, String value) {
        if(Window.confirm("Replace with \"" + value + "\"?"))
            object.setValue(value);
        else {
            cell.clearViewData(object);
            table.redrawRow(index);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How I can get reference to `cell`? There is no such parameter in methods

Comment: You declare the `cell` - I've updated my answer to show the declarations.

Comment: So this `final MyEditTextCell cell = new MyEditTextCell();` store the reference to current cell?

Comment: No, it is cell implementation used in the column. As you can see you pass current object to the `clearViewData` method so the implementation can find data associated with current row.